# Switching theme using Redux is not working

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-persist

This is my configureStore.js file

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {persistStore, persistReducer} from 'redux-persist';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import {stateReducer, themeReducer, authReducer} from './index';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['themeReducer'],
};

const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const rootReducer = combineReducers({stateReducer, themeReducer, authReducer});
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export default () => {
  let store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk)),
  );
  let persistor = persistStore(store);
  return {store, persistor};
};
```

I added `redux-persist` to this file because I want the theme to persist when it is changed. There hasn't been an error when this setup but when I try to change the theme, it doesn't switch. I accessed the theme's state using

```
const theme = useSelector(state => state.themeReducer.theme)
```

This is the `themeReducer`

```
import {lightTheme, darkTheme, SWITCH_THEME} from '../../components/index';

const initialState = {
  theme: lightTheme,
};

const themeReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SWITCH_THEME:
      return {
        theme: action.theme,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default themeReducer;
```

And this is the `switchTheme` action

```
import {SWITCH_THEME} from './../../redux';

export const switchTheme = theme => {
  try {
    return dispatch => {
      dispatch({
        type: SWITCH_THEME,
        theme: theme,
      });
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

The theme switch is in the `DrawerContent` file as below. the `theme.state` has a boolean value.

```
   <Drawer.Section>
      <Preferences>Preferences</Preferences>
      <TouchableRipple onPress={() => {
          theme.mode === 'light'
            ? dispatch(switchTheme(darkTheme))
            : dispatch(switchTheme(lightTheme));
          console.log('Theme state: ', theme.state);
          console.log('Theme mode: ', theme.mode);
        }}>
        <View style={styles.preference}>
          <Text style={{color: theme.text}}>Dark Theme</Text>
          <View pointerEvents="none">
            <Switch value={theme.state} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableRipple>
    </Drawer.Section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution. I was importing `SWITCH_THEME` from the wrong place in the `themeReducer`.